# Wifi Issues on 18.04 (Kernel 4.18.0-15-generic)

Tags: wireless, 18.04, bluetooth, ralink, mediatek

I have been having a lot of trouble with the WIFI on my device. It has a RT 3290 wifi card which runs very poorly (frequently disconnecting, poor signal, super low speed, Bluetooth doesnt work) and I have to be literally on top of my router to connect to a network. In order to solve this I went ahead and bought a nano usb wifi adaptor which was a 148f:7601 Ralink chipset which although is recognised in lsusb , doesnt scan or show networks. Most answers have drivers etc which fail to load on my system due to kernel differences. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

The wireless info file can be seen here- https://github.com/abh1kudo/Ubuntu-Stuff/blob/master/wireless-info.txt

Thanks

Comment: Update- I have also added the dmesg immediately after plugging in the usb wifi dongle. Thanks for the help https://github.com/abh1kudo/Ubuntu-Stuff/blob/master/dmesg.txt

Answer (score 0):

On our Ryzen mobo, we don’t have WIFI network under Kernel 4.19.x or Ubuntu 19.04 if Secure Boot is enabled. On custom kernel (unsigned), we must tweak Secure Boot on startup to keep it enabled: Booting in insecure mode.

**Since last Grub updates: V1.93.13 & V 8.12**

```
sudo mokutil  --disable-validation
```

Try disabling Secure Boot in BIOS to see if the device works or scans better. You may also go for the latest stable Kernel (4.20.10) or the latest long-term one (4.19.23). See if you get a better response.

Since Kernel 4.20.3, the WIFi network rarely fails and on Kernel 5.0 it works normally.  Is connectivity enabled in Settings?

Check for the latest there:
https://www.kernel.org/
Get the PPA there:
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D

```
~$ mokutil  --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled

dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-unsigned-4.20.10-042010-generic  4.20.10-042010.201902150516                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.20.10 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-050000rc7-generic 5.0.0-050000rc7.201902180332                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Network Card

```
lspci -k | more
…
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 P
CI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822
Subsystem: Lenovo Device b024
Kernel driver in use: r8822be
```

To increase speed we are using Adguard DNS (Russian) or Cloudflare DNS. They both have good response.

```
curl -I http://www.cloudflare.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 00:34:45 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 01:34:45 GMT
Location: https://www.cloudflare.com/
Set-Cookie: __cflb=1594113181; Secure; path=/; expires=Wed, 20-Feb-19 23:34:45 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=1e273dcaf653df47ecda89c7783c39cb49c06bad-1550622885-1800-AX7B/ztdd9BR3pmoG+i7Jia3vSqRZ6i8POb6MKW/xcYbvmP3jp51S28spPj/HgDgea1Nqd0qKWSjPILRs9RsArc=; path=/; expires=Wed, 20-Feb-19 01:04:45 GMT; domain=.cloudflare.com; HttpOnly
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 4abce3 …
```

https://adguard.com/en/adguard-dns/overview.html#instruction

https://cloudflare-dns.com/